# Trying to get a turtle breed to avoid a specific colour of patch

Tags: netlogo

;num-Holes is actually a global variable. I'm trying to get them to avoid the black patches(holes in the floor)

```
if any? Patches in-Radius num-Holes with[pcolor = black] 
[
set heading (towards min-one-of num-Holes[distance myself]) + 180 - random 10 + random 10   
]
```

I'm trying to get my zombies to try and avoid black patches
I know that netlogo won't accept the global 'num-Holes' so how can I get it to see and avoid the patches ?
here is a wider scope of the code incase that makes my problem clearer.

```
     to go
   ask zombies
   [
   ;set heading (heading + 45 - (random 90))
    let closest-player min-one-of players[distance myself]
    set heading towards closest-player
    ;wait 1
    forward 1
        if pcolor = black [Death]
        if pcolor = black [Death]

    ;num-Holes is actually a global variable. I'm trying to get them to avoid the black patches(holes in the floor)
    if any? Patches in-Radius num-Holes with[pcolor = black] 
    [
    set heading (towards min-one-of zombies[distance myself]) + 180 - random 10 + random 10   
    ]   ]
end
```

please and thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if any? Patches in-radius 5 with[pcolor = black] [ stuff]
```

Comment: I'm getting this runtime error for one of my variables

"MIN-ONE-OF expected input to be an agentset but got the number 2 instead."
nume-Holes is a slider variable

I have the code block as follows " if any? Patches in-Radius num-Holes with[pcolor = black] 
    [
    set heading (towards min-one-of num-Holes[distance myself]) + 180 - random 10 + random 10   
    ]"

Comment: You should ask that as a new question. The question  formation is much easier to read.

Comment: Yo thanks very much for your help.In the end my solution was this:


  ask patches in-radius 5
    [
      if pcolor = black
      [
        ask myself[set heading (towards min-one-of patches [distance myself]) + 180 - random 10 + random 10 ]
      ]
    ]

Answer (score 3):

As your code is written, it seems you have set num-Holes to be an agent-set.  (Of patches?)  So then you want to change the first line to `if any? (num-Holes in-radius 5)`.

You may also want to look at the zombies models in the NetLogo User Community models.

If `num-Holes` is actually an integer that sets the number of black patches, then you want to take a different approach: first collect the black patches.  It would be best to introduce a global `holes` for this.

```
globals [holes]

to setup
  create-holes  ;; e.g., ask n-of num-Holes patches [set pcolor black]
  set holes patches with [pcolor = black]
end setup

to set-zombie-heading  ;; zombie proc
  if any? holes in-radius 5 [
    set heading (towards min-one-of holes [distance myself]) + 180
    set heading (heading + random 20 - 10)
  ]
end
```

Comment: num-Holes is not an agent set sadly :( it is a global slider variable that adjusts the number of black patches, thereby increasing the size of the  holes.
Any ideas for a solution still please ?

Comment: Yo thanks very much for your help.In the end my solution was this:


  ask patches in-radius 5
    [
      if pcolor = black
      [
        ask myself[set heading (towards min-one-of patches [distance myself]) + 180 - random 10 + random 10 ]
      ]
    ]